# Compressing arrays using Principal Component Analysis (PCA)

Tags: pca, python

I have a (4096x1) vector. I want to compress it to (64x1).

What I did is basically chunking (4096x1) vector to 64 pieces, and getting the mean at each piece.

But getting mean of each chunk in my case is not reliable solution. Because I have many (O)s in my vector, so getting the mean in a chunk might cover the importance of high non zero values in the vector.

I want to try PCA. In python, how I can apply PCA on a (4096x1) to reduce it to (64x1) vector?

Thanks,

Comment: PCA doesn't work on a single vector. Rather, it requires a collection of many vectors. Can you say more about what your goal is and the structure of your data?

Comment: Basically, I have feature vectors if images. There are around 1.5 million of feature vectors. Each feature vector has (4096x1) dimension. I want to train an RNN network by using these vectors. But since they are so many, I get memory crash when I launch training. If I can manage to reduce them to (64x1) dimensions, it would be very convenient for me to launch training. The issue is, I need to somehow compress my feature vectors by not ruining the sequence of distribution in the vectors.

Comment: Ok, so you have a 4096x1.5M matrix, where rows are features and columns are datapoints. You can certainly apply PCA to that (sounds like a pretty typical use case). It will have the further benefit of decorrelating the inputs to your network, which is often recommended as pre-processing for neural nets. If treating pixels as dimensions and images as data points, PCA won't disturb the sequence of images. Implementation questions (e.g. 'how to do this in python') aren't really on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

The point of PCA is to correlate the data to convert it from a multi-dimensional vector into a lower dimension. This is done by only selecting the eigenvectors with the largest eigenvalue. IE only selecting the dimensions which have most variance.

Therefore, for your case where you only have a single dimensional vector this is not possible.

From reading the comments i see that you need it for an RNN. What i suggest is that you reduce the size of the vector, either by max-pooling, or average-pooling prior to feeding it to the RNN. 
Other options include using maxpooling with a convolutional net before to try and extract information for the RNN but this increases the complexity of your network. Without additional information about the application, i cannot really give more insight to this.

Hope this helps!